# Creating both has_many belongs_to associations child and parents model at same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

So I have two models:

```
#app/models/diy.rb
class Diy < Activerecord::Base
   #schema id | summary | created_at | updated_at 
   has_many :steps
end

#app/models/step.rb
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
   # schema id | step_content | photo | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :diy
end
```

Is there any way to create a diy database row and associated with it step database rows in the same view?

Closest I've got is:

```
 <%= form_for(@diy) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :summary  %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :summary %><br>
   <%= f.label :steps  %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :steps %><br>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

but with this code I'm not accessing any columns in step table.

If it helps to solve the problem, with this code i get "Steps" text field which is already filled with "Step::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x9613ce0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Diy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :diy
end
```

[`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) lets Diy take attributes for Steps:

```
Diy.create( steps_attributes: [{ step_content: 'Stir it.' }] )
```

To create the form inputs use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for):

```
<%= form_for(@diy) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :summary  %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :summary %><br>
   <%- # wrapping it in a fieldset element is optional -%>
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Steps</legend>
     <% f.fields_for(:steps) do |step_fields| %>
        <%= step_fields.label :step_content  %><br>
        <%= step_fields.text_field :step_content %><br>
     <% end %>
   </fieldset>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

What this does it iterate though `@diy.steps` and creates a `<textarea name="diy[steps_attributes][][step_content]">` for each. `step_fields` is a form builder which is scoped to the particular nested record.

Note that if `@diy.steps` is nil like on a new record then there will be no form inputs. To solve that you need to seed the record:

```
class DiysController

  # ...
  def new
    @diy = Diy.new
    @diy.steps.new # creates a new step that the user can fill in.
  end

  def edit
    @diy = Diy.find(params[:id])
    @diy.steps.new # creates a new step that the user can fill in.
  end
end
```

To avoid getting a bunch of junk steps you would use the `reject_if` option:

```
class Diy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

To whitelist the nested attributes in your controller use a array containing the allowed attributes:

```
def diy_params
  params.require(:diy).permit(:summary, steps_attributes: [:step_content])
end
```

## Please read:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@Max`'s answer, you'll want to use the following:

```
#app/models/diy.rb
class Diy < Activerecord::Base
   #schema id | summary | created_at | updated_at 
   has_many :steps
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
end

#app/controllers/diys_controller.rb
class DiysController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @diy = Diy.new
      @diy.steps.build
   end

   def create
      @diy = Diy.new diy_params
      @diy.save
   end

   private

   def diy_params
      params.require(:diy).permit(steps_attributes: [:step_content])
   end
end

#app/views/diys/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @diy do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :steps do |s| %>
      <%= s.number_field :step_count %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

If you wanted to just associate new `Diy`'s to existing `Step`s, you'll want to populate the `step_ids` ([`collection_singular_ids`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Ahas_many)) attribute:

```
#controller
def diy_params
   params.require(:diy).permit(step_ids: [])
end

#app/views/diys/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @diy do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :step_ids, Step.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```